# How can I overwrite or save an existing local HTML file that's edited in a UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, file, uiwebview, local

The app uses a UIWebView to load up local HTML files (which are now just text) for editing. I need to save whats been edited by the user back to the local file. This is the only way I could think of doing that:

Once the text has been edited by the user, I've written a save method that takes the current HTML in the web view and saves it to an HTML file (with the same fileName as the original) which is written to the documents directory. In theory this should overwrite the original. But it doesn't.

```
-(void)save{
    NSError *err;
    NSString * docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *oldFile = [self.webView.request.URL lastPathComponent];
    //Above line gets the actual HTML file name that's in the webview
    NSString * path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:oldFile];
    //The following line gets what html code is in the actual webview
    NSString *html = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML"];

    [html writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

No file seems to be written. It doesn't overwrite the original nor does it write a new one.

Perhaps I shouldn't be saving it this way, but I can't think of any other methods of doing it.

Comment: Two observations: 1. You might want to actually pass `&err` to `writeToFile`'s `error` parameter. Check the result and see if `err` is `nil`, and if not, look at error object and see what it says. Having said that, I use `NSString` method `writeToFile` and it overwrites, so I'm not sure what the issue is. 2. Unrelated to your issue, it may be safer to build `docsDir` using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];` rather than manually building the `Documents path. It's equivalent, but perhaps a little more "future-proof."

Comment: You might also want to `NSLog` the `path` to make sure it is what you think it should be.

Comment: Path is correct, I made sure to nslog it earlier. And not sure how I forgot to put &err in there, careless mistake. After playing with it, I've noticed that it does work, but only if view another HTML file first. Basically the user can click a 'new' and a new HTML file will be created and loaded into the UIWebView. Upon editing at this point, nothing will save. And I've found that `NSString *oldFile = [self.webView.request.URL lastPathComponent];` returns nil. However, if you create another new blank HTML file(which will be loaded into the web view automatically), and then navigate back...

Comment: to the original HTML file, it will save properly. So the problem lies in `oldFile` pulling in the url of the file being displayed in the web view. But only when the file is first created in loaded in.

Comment: Got it working. Turns out, upon adding html text to the webview for editing when first created, I had `baseURL:` set to nil. `[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[file absoluteURL]];` is the correct implementation. Again, careless mistake. But thanks for the help and the `docsDir` tip.

Comment: hey Joe, i have also same requirement like you can you send me sample code so that i can save the HTML file then again i can open that saved HTML file and re-edit the same.